# How can I select tags using multiple select in iview UI

Tags: vue.js, iview, iview-ui

I want to select not only from select drop down options, also I want to add custom tags from users input. In current select, I can only select multiple items from the available itemlists array. But I want to select what ever users insert. Is it possible in iView?

```
<Select v-model="model9" filterable multiple>
     <Option v-for="item in cityList" :value="item.value" :key="item.value">{{ item.label }}</Option>
</Select>
```

Current problem is, user can only select from the array `cityList` but I want any custom input from the user.

Thank you.

Comment: no, iview unsupport custom value in `<Select>`, but you could add `<Input>` outside.

Comment: Hi sadek, can you make a jsFiddle example so its more clear for me the problem? I am one of the iview members and involved in the Select component. Happy to help...

Answer (score 0):

In **v4.0.0** there is an `allow-create` prop which allows you to create new items.

```html
<Select v-model="model18" filterable multiple allow-create @on-create="handleCreate2">
    <Option v-for="item in cityList4" :value="item.value" :key="item.value">{{ item.label }}</Option>
</Select>
```